# Google Now suddenly disappeared

Tags: applications, samsung-galaxy-nexus, 4.2-jelly-bean, google-now, google-search

I'm running Android 4.2.2 on a Galaxy Nexus with the February 13, 2013 update of Google Search installed. **Google Now was working great until it suddenly ceased to appear today.** Widgets now display "Get Google Now", and the Google Now screen itself only contains a search box, not even showing the Google Now-related items that were in the settings menu previously.

I rebooted the phone multiple times and upgraded all apps, but the problem has persisted for the last few hours. What gives, and **is there a way to "reset" Google Now?**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why Google Now ceased to appear, but here is how to reset it:

1. Open `Settings --> Apps.`
2. Scroll right to `All`.
3. Open Google Search, hit `Clear Data` and `Clear Cache`.

Open `Google Now` again and it will walk you through the initial setup guide. My personalized card settings were retained after the clear.